# "Access Denied" Message when trying to copy file(s) pulled with JGit

Tags: java, file, permissions, jgit

I have some java code that goes ahead and pulls code from a git repository that I have access to. The files are properly pulled locally.

When I try to copy the files with the `Files.copy()` method in `java.io.file` from one local destination to another, I get the following error thrown:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Some\Path\dir (Access is denied)`

I have already added the following code in attempt to change the file permissions:

```
fileInitialLocation.setReadable(true, false);
fileInitialLocation.setExecutable(true, false);
fileInitialLocation.setWritable(true, false);

fileFinalLocation.setReadable(true, false);
fileFinalLocation.setExecutable(true, false);
fileFinalLocation.setWritable(true, false);
```

What can I change to properly copy the files from the initial location to the final location to prevent the access denied error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the file name when copying.

```
File fileForCopy = new File("C:\Some\Path\dir\fileName.txt");
```

If you need to copy whole folder try `Apache Commons IO` [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory-java.io.File-java.io.File-).

Comment: I create the files like this: `File a = new File(aPath);` `File b = new File(bPath);`. Then I do the set commands. Then, `Files.copy(a,b);` Where `aPath` and `bPath` are paths to the respective files.

Comment: What is the full value of the variables aPath nad bPath ?

Comment: C:\Users\jack\Desktop\gitRepo

Comment: You mised file name.

Comment: That part of the answer (needing to copy the whole folder) was what I needed. Thanks!